# How to pass data from Adapter class to TabView Layout?

Tags: android

I am trying to pass data Adapter class to TabView Layout. I have used fragment in tab. I want to pass data from adapter to fragment (fragment class for tab).

________________________________________Adapter Class________________________________________________

```
package com.livediscount.restaurants.Adapter;

public class LiveContestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LiveContestAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    List<Contest_Data> contest_data;

    public LiveContestAdapter(Context context,  List<Contest_Data> contest_data) {
        this.context=context;
        this.contest_data=contest_data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        context=viewGroup.getContext();
        View vh= LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_win_iphone,viewGroup,false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder(vh);

        return myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final LiveContestAdapter.MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
        final Contest_Data contest_position = contest_data.get(i);
        Picasso.with(context).load(contest_data.get(i).getContestImage()).error(R.drawable.damme).placeholder(R.drawable.damme).into(myViewHolder.img);
        myViewHolder.remainSlot.setText(contest_data.get(i).getContestTotal_slot());
        myViewHolder.ent_fee.setText(contest_data.get(i).getContestEntry_Fee());
        myViewHolder.Booked_Slot.setText(contest_data.get(i).getContestBooked());
        final String contest_status = contest_data.get(i).getContestStatus();
        String previous_contest = contest_data.get(i).getPrevious_contest();
        String winner_announce = contest_data.get(i).getWinner_announce();





    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contest_data.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView name;
        ImageView img;



        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //name=itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalslot);
            img=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            htp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            remainSlot=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalSlotNumber);

        }

    }

}
```

___________________________________________AppCompactActivity______________________________________

```
public class PrizeBreakup extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton back;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    String contest_id,contest_name;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prize_breakup);



        back = findViewById(R.id.back_button);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        tabLayout= findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);

        PrizeLayoutAdapter adapter = new PrizeLayoutAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.add(new PrizeLayout(),"Prize Breakup");
        adapter.add(new WinnerLayout(),"Winners");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

//here
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("contestid1", "contest_id");
editor.apply();

       /* Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        assert bundle!= null;
        contest_id = bundle.getString("contest_id");
        contest_name = bundle.getString("contest_name");*/

        /* Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("contestid1","contest_id");
        Fragment argumentFragment = new PrizeLayout();

        argumentFragment.setArguments(data);*/


    }
}
```

_____________________________________PrizeLayout Fragment________________________________________

```
    package com.livediscount.restaurants;

public class PrizeLayout extends Fragment  {

    List<Contest_Data> contest_data;
    LiveContestAdapter live_contest_adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView ContestId;



    public static PrizeLayout newInstance() {
        return new PrizeLayout();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater,  ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prize_layout, container, false);
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String contestid = getActivity().prefs.getString("contestid1", "contestid not found");

        String Contest_id = this.getArguments().getString("edttext");
        ContestId= view.findViewById(R.id.referral_code);
        ContestId.setText(contestid);

        return view;
    }


}
```

________________________________________Winner Fragment______________________________________________

```
    package com.livediscount.restaurants;

public class WinnerLayout extends Fragment {

    private List<Winner_data> winner_data=new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView_winner;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container , Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.winner_layout,container,false);

        recyclerView_winner = view.findViewById(R.id.Recyclerview_Winner);
        if(winner_data!=null)
        {
            winner_data.clear();
        }
        Winner_Data();


        return view;
    }

    private void Winner_Data() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String url = ("http://livediscounts.in/webservices/User_interface/Winner_List?contest_id=\"+razorpayPaymentID+\"");

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    //progressBar_contest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("1")) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("records");
                        /*for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Winner_data wd = new Winner_data();
                            cd.setContestId(obj.getString("id"));
                            cd.setContestName(obj.getString("name"));
                            cd.setContestImage(obj.getString("prize_1"));
                            cd.setContestDescription(obj.getString("description"));
                            cd.setContestType(obj.getString("type"));
                            cd.setContestEntry_Fee(obj.getString("entry_fee"));
                            cd.setContestTotal_slot(obj.getString("total_slot"));
                            cd.setContestTotal_winner(obj.getString("total_winner"));
                            cd.setContestPrice_Description(obj.getString("price_description"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_21(obj.getString("prize_21"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_22(obj.getString("prize_22"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_31(obj.getString("prize_31"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_32(obj.getString("prize_32"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_41(obj.getString("prize_41"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_42(obj.getString("prize_42"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_51(obj.getString("prize_51"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_52(obj.getString("prize_52"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_61(obj.getString("prize_61"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_62(obj.getString("prize_62"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_71(obj.getString("prize_71"));
                            cd.setContestPrize_72(obj.getString("prize_72"));
                            cd.setContestStatus(obj.getString("status"));
                            cd.setContestContest_Note(obj.getString("contest_note"));
                            cd.setContestStart_date(obj.getString("start_date"));
                            cd.setContestEnd_date(obj.getString("end_date"));
                            cd.setContestBooked(obj.getString("booked_slot"));

                            winner_data.add(wd);

                        }*/
                        /*WinnerAdapter winnerAdapter = new WinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), winner_data);
                        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
                        recyclerView_winner.setLayoutManager(llm);
                        recyclerView_winner.setAdapter(winnerAdapter);*/

                    } else {
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    //progressBar_contest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); ex.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }
                ,
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No Internet Connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }

        );
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use shared pref using parent activity.

Comment: Can you please change in program? So i can understand better... Thanks

Comment: did it help? @arpitsingh